# Can you help me solve this node js error? "Module_Not_Found"

Tags: node.js

[Image of code, execution and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEIS6.png)

When I try to run `node fordongu.js` in the terminal, I get this error. Would you suggest an idea of ​​how to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states that there's no file `fordungo.js` in the directory you're trying to execute from. So it seems you're in the wrong folder and need to `cd` into `javascript tekrar\for döngüleri` and execute the script from there.

Comment: where cd folder

Comment: ı m new node js

Comment: `cd`-ing into the right directory has nothing to do with nodejs ;) I think you should be able to figure that out :) But if it helps - just right-click `fordungo.js` in vscode and click on  "Open in Terminal" -> vscode will automatically cd into the right directory

Comment: @xYusufX reading a guide on how to navigate in cmd: [CMD navigation](https://riptutorial.com/cmd/example/8646/navigating-in-cmd), might help you a bit.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please accept it - thanks.

Comment: @xYusufX, for further questions: I believe if you looked into the problem a bit more you would be able to find a solution, and if not - please provide the things you have tried! Also, instead of posting an image of the problem you could include the error code as text.

Comment: I tried but it didn't. I opened vscode. I clicked on the new terminal. I changed from powershell to cmd. cd "E: \ Vs code run JAVASCRIPT". I tried the same process powershell. It was not

Comment: .... one more time  - open vscode, right click the file you want to execute in the explorer (on the left). vscode then automatically opens a new terminal with the directory the file exists in.

Comment: Thank you very much you solved the problem I could not solve for 3 weeks. Thank you very very very much.